# I want to use Microsoft Security Code Analysis in Azure DevOps is there any cost involved with it for using it in scanning the code

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I want to use Microsoft Security Code Analysis in Azure DevOps is there any cost involved with it.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this doc: [Onboarding and installing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/develop/security-code-analysis-onboard)

> If you have one of the following support offerings, contact your Technical Account Manager to purchase or swap existing hours to get access to the extension.
> If you do not have one of the mentioned above support agreements, you can purchase the extension from one of our Partners.

Based on the doc, you need to purchase for this tool. So it is not free.

You need to contact the corresponding email to obtain the specific payment method